# Any non-trivial $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ contains an eigenvector of $T.$

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, invariant-subspace

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$.
>   Deduce that if the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits, then any
>   non-trivial $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ contains an eigenvector of
>   $T.$

Let $W$ be a $T$-Invariant subspace. $W\neq\{0\}$($\because$ Given that $W$ is non-trivial). The characteristic polynomial of $T$ restricted to $W$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $T$. I am not able to proceed further. I need to prove $\exists v\neq 0, v\in W: T(v)=\lambda v$. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Since the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits, so does characteristic polynomial of $T|W$.

Comment: characteristic polynomial of $T|_{W}$ splits. Let $W_1$ be the matrix representation  $T|_{W}$ of the standard basis. $\det(W_1-tI)=0$ has solution. so, there exists $v\in W: T(v)=\lambda v$. right?

Comment: Am I correct?can you please tell me?